# Code to keep score of a game

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write the part of code that keeps track of wins, losses and ties in rock paper scissors. The program runs successfully however, it freezes when I enter the results screen (maybe due to the code). This is the code for results. Main issue is at the buttom with the "do" statements. Here it is:

```
@IBOutlet var yourChoice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var computerChoice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var results: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var score: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreYou: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tiesScore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreYou2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreTies2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreComputer2: UILabel!

var toPass: String!
var aiInfo: String!
var ai = arc4random_uniform(3)
var x: Int = 0 // Player Score
var y: Int = 0 // Ties
var z: Int = 0 // Computer Score

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.yourChoice.text = "Your Choice: \(toPass)"

    if ai == 0 {
        aiInfo = "Rock"
    } else if ai == 1 {
        aiInfo = "Paper"
    } else if ai == 2 {
        aiInfo = "Scissors"
    } else {
        aiInfo = "Unknown"
    }
    self.computerChoice.text = "Computer Choice: \(aiInfo)"

    if toPass == aiInfo {
        self.results.text = "Results: Tie!"
        self.results.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    } else if toPass == "Rock" && aiInfo == "Scissors" {
        self.results.text = "Results: You Win!"
        self.results.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    } else if toPass == "Paper" && aiInfo == "Rock" {
        self.results.text = "Results: You Win!"
        self.results.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    } else if toPass == "Scissors" && aiInfo == "Paper" {
        self.results.text = "Results: You Win!"
        self.results.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    } else {
        self.results.text = "Results: You Lose!"
        self.results.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

    do {
        x + 1
    } while results.text == "Results: You Win!"
    do {
        y + 1
    } while results.text == "Results: Tie!"
    do {
        z + 1
    } while results.text == "Results: You Lose!"

    scoreYou2.text = "\(x)"
    scoreTies2.text = "\(y)"
    scoreComputer2.text = "\(z)"
}
```

Comment: How would these 'do' loops stop?

Comment: Once the user quits the game. Im actually about to implement a button called "play again!" (pretty self explanatory), and i might store the score variables in there so that way it doesnt get reset to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing:

```
do {
        x + 1
    } while results.text == "Results: You Win!"
    do {
        y + 1
    } while results.text == "Results: Tie!"
    do {
        z + 1
    } while results.text == "Results: You Lose!"
```

with:

```
if results.text == "Results: You Win!" {
    x++
}
if results.text == "Results: Tie!" {
    y++
}
if results.text == "Results: You Lose!" {
    z++
}
```

Comment: Doesnt freeze anymore, however, i do need to store the information in scoreYou2, ScoreTies2, and scoreComputer2 labels. Like I told Pleun,i'm about to implement a button called "play again!" (pretty self explanatory), and i might store the score variables in there so that way it doesn't get reset to zero.

Comment: Problem solved, now one now :p  You can see it in the edited post

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem doing it